# How to save AES Key in PEM file

Tags: aes, asn1, pem

I'd like to store a private symmetric key, aes-256, in a PEM file.

My understanding is that usually these types of keys are derived using RSA/EC DH and there's no need to save them, but in my application I do need to save them and share securely.

Is there an standard defined for saving these keys. Is there any openssl API that would help reading the key from the PEM file ?

Also, in case such a format exists, is it possible to add key/value pairs to the file, (these  are only relevant to the application)

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need it to be ASN.1? An AES256 key is just 32 bytes, you can store it in hex or in base64 for convenience. Or you can wrap it with another key, a symmetric or asymmetric one, in a more complex scheme.

Comment: There is definitely no OpenSSL capability for storing a symmetric key (like AES, or also things like HMAC) in PEM, and no such convention or standard anywhere else I know of. You could certainly invent and code your own if you want -- the PEM _concept_ is extensible -- but I can't see any possible benefit. Neither does PGP, although RFC6030 defines an XMLdsig/XMLenc extension (which I've never seen used) and JWK (JWS/JWE/JWT) supports symmetric keys standardly -- if you just want an 'anointed' format you could use that.